# Pick random line from a compressed text file with zcat/gz or altnernatives

Tags: bash, shell-script, compression, gzip, random

I have a simple bash script that picks a random line from a text file. This is originally done with `shuf file.txt | head -1` (the same result can be achieved with `cat file.txt | shuf | head -1`). I also assign the random line to a variable (`a=$(shuf file.txt | head -1)`).

To preserve storage, I compressed the textfile (`gzip file.txt`) and attempted to use `zcat`, as in `zcat file.txt.gz | shuf | head -1`, but this results in bash trying to execute each line from the file.txt.gz (e.g. `file.txt: line 1589: examplestring: command not found`).

How can I pick a random line from a gzip compressed text file in bash? I'm not aversed to using alternative compression methods.

*edit:* My initial approach (`a=$(zcat file.txt.gz | shuf | head -1)`) works as expected, I must have overlooked a typo, which I can't seem to reproduce. The approach proposed by @gogoud feels better though.

Comment: Your proposed pipeline with `zcat` ought to have worked as you have written it. Could you possibly revisit the command that you used to see if you actually wrote it the way you wrote it in your question?

Comment: @they you're absolutely right. I just retried the initial approach and it worked. I must have had a nasty typo, which I can't reproduce anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me with bash 5.0.17(1):

```
zcat file.txt.gz | shuf -n1
```